# how to generate empty array in json4s?

Tags: arrays, list, scala, json4s

I've 2 bits of scala code using the json4s dsl to produce json content

```
val feastWithMenus = "Feast" ->
("target" -> "me") ~
  ("menus" -> List(
    ("first" -> "pate") ~
      ("mains" -> "beef") ~
      ("dessert" -> "ice-cream")
    ,
    ("first" -> "soup") ~
      ("mains" -> "omlette") ~
      ("dessert" -> "ice-cream")
  ))

  val feastNoMenu = "Feast" ->
("target" -> "me") ~ 
  ("menus" -> List.empty)
```

In the first instance, I get what I'm expecting:

```
{"Feast":{"target":"me","menus":[{"first":"pate","mains":"beef","dessert":"ice-cream"},     {"first":"soup","mains":"omlette","dessert":"ice-cream"}]}}

JObject(List((Feast,JObject(List((target,JString(me)), (menus,JArray(List(JObject(List((first,JString(pate)), (mains,JString(beef)), (dessert,JString(ice-cream)))), JObject(List((first,JString(soup)), (mains,JString(omlette)), (dessert,JString(ice-cream))))))))))))
```

but for the empty list I don't get an array. Instead I get

```
{"Feast":{"target":"me","menus":{}}}

JObject(List((Feast,JObject(List((target,JString(me)), (menus,JObject(List())))))))
```

Notice in the first case menus is a `JArray(List(Jobject` and in the second it's a `JObject(List()`

Is this by design? this is currently for testing but I need to understand what's going on as my real world code will potentially have empty lists in a number of places and recipient is expecting an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an explicit type supported by json4s to the `List` constructor in order to make things work, otherwise `Nothing` will be inferred.

Comment: val feastNoMenu = "Feast" ->
("target" -> "me") ~ 
  ("menus" -> List.empty[JInt])